# Calculate the difference between two stamps based on another column

Tags: pandas, timestamp, time-series

I have the following sample data. I would like to calculate holding time for each unique id, which is nothing the difference between two timestamps for that id.

For example: (20171116 03:46:17.467893 - 20171116 03:46:16.142514) for id1, (20171116 03:46:17.212341 - 20171116 03:46:16.243121) for id2,  so on and so forth.

```
                   DATETIME   INSTR MODE TYPE  id
0  20171116 03:46:16.142514  INSTR1  ORD  New   1
4  20171116 03:46:17.467893  INSTR1  ORD  CXL   1
1  20171116 03:46:16.243121  INSTR2  ORD  New   2
3  20171116 03:46:17.212341  INSTR2  ORD  TRD   2
2  20171116 03:46:16.758292  INSTR3  ORD  New   3
5  20171116 03:46:18.924825  INSTR3  ORD  TRD   3
```

Can someone help me..Many Thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column `DATETIME` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then `groupby` with subtract last value with first:

```
df['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME'])

df = df.groupby('id')['DATETIME']
       .apply(lambda x: x.iat[-1] - x.iat[0]).reset_index(name='timedelta')
```

Or subtract by [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) and [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
g = df.groupby('id')['DATETIME']
df = (g.last() - g.first()).reset_index(name='timedelta')
```

---

```
print (df)

   id       timedelta
0   1 00:00:01.325379
1   2 00:00:00.969220
2   3 00:00:02.166533
```